# Android MVP - where should i read from Textview?

Tags: java, android, mvp

After a user clicks a button i want to read what's in the TextViews of the activity and then call a method from the presenter to get a return based on the info sent to it.

However i don't know if the presenter should get this data by itself or if i should pass to him from the Activity class when i call one of his methods (this would mean get the data in the TextFields inside the activity class and then send the data as parameters when i call a Presenter method).

I've tried both methods but i don't know which one is the more organised way to do this.

Comment: You have to get data inside the Activity and then pass it to presenter as a function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will pass the string to the presenter wanted method , then do what you want .

```
button.setOnClickListenr(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String str = myTextView.getText().toString();
    presenter.doSomething(str);
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the MVP architecture pattern, you're supposed to have a reference to the `Presenter` on the `View` (in this case, the `View`is your `Activity`). They have very **different responsibilities**:

- Your `View` should be as dumb as possible, i.e., it should only be responsible for displaying whatever data to the user and collecting user input.
- Your `Presenter`should be responsible for both handling all the data that is displayed on the `View` and acting as a middleman between the `View` and the `Model`. In other words, for each possible user input, there should be a method in the `Presenter` capable of handling it.

For instance, in your case, the `View`is responsible for handling the contents of the TextView over to the `Presenter`. Then, the `Presenter` has to pass those contents down to the `Model`, which does something with it according to your business logic. When the `Model` finishes processing, it returns the result to the `Presenter`, which then **prepares the content** to be displayed on the `View`. When the content is ready, the `Presenter` then sends it to the `View`.

Knowing all of this, you should be able to answer your question. It would be something like this (pseudo code):

```
class MyActivity
{
  // you should inject this
  Presenter myPresenter;

  TextView myTextView;

  ...

  myPresenter.doStuff(myTextView.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need read what's in the TextViews? 
All data show in View should come from Presenter.
Your data should save in your Repository, Presenter can get everything that you want in your Repository.